# Replace values of dataframe columns using a nested dictionnary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm having a question regarding replacing values of multiple columns in a dataframe using a nested dictionnary. Here is the dataframe as a reproductible example:

```
fill_data = [
    ['Tom', 'DE_400001_A_1M', 'PLUS_1M', 'DE_250001_A_500000', 'DE_5001_A_10000', 'PLUS_DE_8001'], 
    ['Nick', 'DE_1M_A_2M', 'PLUS_1M', 'DE_50001_A_250000', 'PLUS_DE_10001', 'DE_2001_A_4000'], 
    ['Juli', 'PLUS_2M', 'DE_50001_A_1M', 'PLUS_500000', 'DE_3001_A_5000', 'DE_4001_A_8000']
]
df = pd.DataFrame(
    fill_data,
    columns = [
        'Name',
        'tranchePatrimoineImmobilier',
        'tranchePatrimoineLiquidites',
        'tranchePatrimoineFinancier',
        'trancheRevenusReguliersNetsMensuels',
        'trancheCapaciteEpargneMensuelle'
    ]
)
```

Now, here is the nested dictionnary that I want to use to replace values of the columns of the df:

```
nested_dict = { 'tranchePatrimoineImmobilier': {
    'DE_400001_A_1M': 1,
    'DE_1M_A_2M': 2,
    'PLUS_2M': 3
},
'tranchePatrimoineLiquidites': {
    'DE_50001_A_1M': 1,
    'PLUS_1M': 2
},
'tranchePatrimoineFinancier': {
    'DE_50001_A_250000': 1,
    'DE_250001_A_500000': 2,
    'PLUS_500000': 3
},
'trancheRevenusReguliersNetsMensuels': {
    'DE_3001_A_5000': 1,
    'DE_5001_A_10000': 2,
    'PLUS_DE_10001': 3
},
'trancheCapaciteEpargneMensuelle': {
    'DE_2001_A_4000': 1,
    'DE_4001_A_8000': 2,
    'PLUS_DE_8001': 3
}
}
```

General idea would be to detect the fact that for each column name that I want to modify, there is a key in the nested dictionnary with the same name. The dataframe column is fill with the various keys of the nested dictionnary and I want to replace them with the corresponding values.
The expected output would be:

```
fill_data = [
    ['Tom', '1', '2', '2', '2', '3'], 
    ['Nick', '2', '2', '1', '3', '1'], 
    ['Juli', '3', '1', '3', '1', '2']
]
df = pd.DataFrame(
    fill_data,
    columns = [
        'Name',
        'tranchePatrimoineImmobilier',
        'tranchePatrimoineLiquidites',
        'tranchePatrimoineFinancier',
        'trancheRevenusReguliersNetsMensuels',
        'trancheCapaciteEpargneMensuelle'
    ]
)
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [pandas.Series.map](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html)

```
for column, values in nested_dict.items():
    df[column] = df[column].map(values)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df[col] = df[col].map(nested_dict[col])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html#pandas.DataFrame.replace) on the entire dataframe, with a nested dictionary input the top-level keys are taken to be column names for which the values are dicts of replacements for that column:

```py
out = df.replace(nested_dict)
```

Output:

```
   Name  tranchePatrimoineImmobilier  tranchePatrimoineLiquidites
0   Tom                            1                            2  \
1  Nick                            2                            2
2  Juli                            3                            1

   tranchePatrimoineFinancier  trancheRevenusReguliersNetsMensuels
0                           2                                    2  \
1                           1                                    3
2                           3                                    1

   trancheCapaciteEpargneMensuelle
0                                3
1                                1
2                                2
```

From the manual:

> For a DataFrame nested dictionaries, e.g., {'a': {'b': np.nan}}, are read as follows: look in column ‘a’ for the value ‘b’ and replace it with NaN. The optional value parameter should not be specified to use a nested dict in this way